# Approval Process Error in Apex test code

Tags: unit-test, error, approval-process

When i run the test class in Apex Test Execution,the test methods get passed ,but the code coverage is just  50% displayed in the developer console.Error message when i add the approval process line.

> NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process was found

These are lines added

```
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                       req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
                       req1.setObjectId(getid);
                       req1.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{userid });
                       Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
```

Any help very much appreciated
Test Class :

```
 @isTest
public class Test_ApprovalProcessLeadController {
   Public static testMethod void sapld() {

        user u =[select id,Profile_Name__c from user  limit 1];

        lead l = new lead();
        l.lastname='Test';
        l.company='test';
        l.email='abc@test.com';       
        l.Approval_flag__c=false; 
        l.Rep_Managing_Partner__c= u.id;
        l.Approval_Status__c='Pending Approval'; 
        l.Country='USA';  
        insert l;
         System.AssertEquals(l.Id!=null,True);
        test.startTest();
         ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', l.id);
         ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(l);         
         ApprovalProcessLeadController a = new ApprovalProcessLeadController(controller);
           // test.startTest();
            a.getdetails();
            a.Redirect();
            test.stoptest();
        }

     Public static testMethod void sapld1() 
        {

         Account acc11 = new Account(Name='Testing SubscriptionClone', BillingStreet='Banjara hills', BillingCity='Hyd', BillingState='TS',
                                    BillingPostalCode = '500084', BillingCountry = 'India', Phone = '100', Industry = 'Banking',
                                    Type = 'Paid', Customer_Type__c = 'Customer', Customer_List__c = true);
        insert acc11 ;
        contact cc11 = new contact(FirstName ='Test Contact Subscription', LastName ='Opptyclone', Role__c='Subscription Administrator',AccountId=acc11.Id);
        insert cc11;
        Profile p = [SELECT id ,Name FROM Profile WHERE Name='Custom Partner Community user'];

        User u = new User(
            FirstName = 'test', 
            LastName= 'last_test', 
            Email='test323232@test.com', 
            Phone='111-111-1111', 
            //True_Market_Unit__c='1111', 
            alias = 'test', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            ProfileId = p.Id,
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName = 'test323232@test.com'
            );
         u.ContactId=cc11.Id;
        insert u;
       System.runAs(u) {
             test.startTest();

       // user u =[select id,Profile_Name__c from user WHERE Profile_Name__c='Custom Partner Community user' limit 1];
        System.AssertEquals(u.Id!=null,True);                 
        lead l = new lead();
        l.lastname='Test';
        l.company='test';
        l.email='abc@test.com';
        l.Approval_flag__c=false;
        l.Product_Interest__c='Services';
        l.Rep_Managing_Partner__c = u.id;
        l.Approval_Status__c='Pending Approval'; 
        l.country='USA';                     
        insert l;
        //test.startTest();
         ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', l.id);
         ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(l);          
         ApprovalProcessLeadController a = new ApprovalProcessLeadController(controller);
         //test.startTest();

         a.getdetails();
         a.Redirect();
         test.stoptest();
        } 
      }  
        Public static testMethod void sapld2() 
        {
        Account acc11 = new Account(Name='Testing SubscriptionClone', BillingStreet='Banjara hills', BillingCity='Hyd', BillingState='TS',
                                    BillingPostalCode = '500084', BillingCountry = 'India', Phone = '100', Industry = 'Banking',
                                    Type = 'Paid', Customer_Type__c = 'Customer', Customer_List__c = true);
        insert acc11 ;
        contact cc11 = new contact(FirstName ='Test Contact Subscription', LastName ='Opptyclone', Role__c='Subscription Administrator',AccountId=acc11.Id);
        insert cc11;
        Profile p = [SELECT id ,Name FROM Profile WHERE Name='Custom Partner Community user'];

        User u = new User(
            FirstName = 'test', 
            LastName= 'last_test', 
            Email='test323232@test.com', 
            Phone='111-111-1111', 
            //True_Market_Unit__c='1111', 
            alias = 'test', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            ProfileId = p.Id,
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName = 'test323232@test.com'
            );
         u.ContactId=cc11.Id;
        insert u;
             System.runAs(u) {
             test.startTest();
         // The following code runs as user u2. 
         System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
         System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
        //}


       // user u =[select id,Profile_Name__c from user WHERE Profile_Name__c='Custom Partner Community user' limit 1];
        System.AssertEquals(u.Id!=null,True);       
        lead l = new lead();
        l.lastname='Test';
        l.company='test';
        l.email='abc@test.com';
       //l.CheckCreatedByProfile1__c=false;
        l.Approval_flag__c=true;
        l.Product_Interest__c='Services';      
        l.Rep_Managing_Partner__c = u.id; 
        l.Approval_Status__c='Rejected';
        l.Country='USA';                   
        insert l;

       // test.startTest();
         ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', l.id);
         ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(l);          
         ApprovalProcessLeadController a = new ApprovalProcessLeadController(controller);
        // test.startTest();
         a.getdetails();
         a.Redirect();
         test.stoptest();
        }   
      }    
    }
```

The lines that didnt get covered in developer console is :

```
if(getdata.Approval_flag__c==true)
                         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Approval request is already submitted/Approved '));
                         if(getdata.CheckCreatedByProfile1__c==false)

                               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,' You dont have access to submit this lead for apporval'));                  
                   }
```

Comment: The overall coverage of the code in production need to be 75%. It doesnt necessarily mean that all the classes should have 75%. But the ideally you would have to have all the classes to exceed 75% and also have proper assertions in your classes to check if they are doing exactly what they are intended to do

Comment: @Prady:Thanks for the response.The overall code coverage in production was 23% and the test classes which are having less coverage im modifying the code and now the code coverage came to 73%.These codes were written by some one.I need to move a trigger and test classes but due to the code coverage its stucked.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: I think  you would first need to understand what these triggers are doing. Based on that you would need to write your test codes. It would be very difficult for someone help you with every trigger you have in there. Like i had told you in your previous question, make sure you have the values populated and have them as null based on what your trigger is doing. In this case probably you need to have the values for approvalflag = false and createdbyProfile= true. You would need to look through each if statement and see conditions and accordingly prepare your test data.

Comment: I haven't read through all of your code, i suggest you do it and shoot out any specific questions that you have. i think the community would be more than willing to help you out

Comment: @Prady:Thanks for your response.When i add the approval process lines ,the system started throwing an error as :System.DmlException: Process failed. first error: NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process was found,The Approval process is very well Activated ,but the entry criteria is written on a formulafield.How to call a formula field in a test class.Formula field : CheckCreatedByProfile1__c Formulae is IF( Owner:User.Profile.Id = '00e50000000sH', true, false)Approval Process Entry Criteria  :
Lead: CheckCreatedByProfileEQUALSTrue

Any suggestion please

Comment: You can query formula field in test class like you normally query any other field. I think the issue for you here is that the test is running in System mode so your profile might not be matching the id in formula. You can refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm to run as user with particular profile. Can you reword your question to be specific with the issue you are facing. The question is put on hold and cant be answered.

Comment: @prady:The profile is different ,iam as system admin and the profile is for a partner community.I have edited the question.

Comment: pls read the link i had posted in my earlier comment. There it tells you how you can run the test as a particular user or profile. That way your condition can be satisfied

Comment: @Prady:I tried adding system.runas() but still no luck.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @Prady:I have updated the code.I have tried using System Runas() in the second method :sapld2.

Comment: In the `runas(u)` all you are doing is giving some debug statement. You should have your lead creation and the code between the starttest and stoptest inside the `runas(u)`  code block

Comment: Also is your data satisfying the if conditions? ie `getdata.Product_Interest__c != null` and `getdata.Approval_flag__c!=true && getdata.CheckCreatedByProfile1__c==true || (getdata.Approval_Status__c =='Rejected')`

Comment: @Prady:Runas() should be given as test method as we give for the testclass test methods and do the insertion.Can we give formula fields in the test class,here checkcreatedByprofile1__c is a formula field.Any suggestion very much appreciated.

Comment: @Prady:As suggested i have updated the code and the code coverage has increased to 82%.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that is not covered is because your test records are not satisfying the if / else conditions. Make sure your test data is prepared accordingly. For eg. `getdata.Product_Interest__c != null` and `getdata.Approval_flag__c!=true && getdata.CheckCreatedByProfile1__c==true`

For the code part where you are checking for if a user is of a particular profile, you need to run the test as user of a profile. To do this you need to use `runas()`. Refer the link
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

```
@isTest
private class TestRunAs {
   public static testMethod void testRunAs() {
      // Setup test data
      // This code runs as the system user
      Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
      User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');

      System.runAs(u) {
         // The following code runs as user 'u' 
         System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
         System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
         //You need to add your test code in this code block to run as a particular user
      }
   }
}
```

As for your question regarding the setting of formula field in test class. You cant directly edit the formula field. But you can manipulate the fields which are used in the formula field. ie. if you have a formula field called `Total = Rate * quantity`, you get the desired value for Total you need to change the values of Rate and Quantity.